# Unable to edit questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

I had the privilege of editing questions and someone will review the edit and grant it or reject it, it looks like I can't see the *edit* link now under questions, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual reason you can't see the edit link is because somebody else that doesn't have outright permission to edit has made an edit to the post and that edit is still waiting for approval / rejection (or the approval queue is already full). See [this answer on the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84676/159222).

The only other time I've noticed it is here on Meta, where the Edit link is only visible on Community Wiki posts.